# What is 'active' about this question?

Tags: support, recent-activity

Usually when CrossValidated marks a question as "active today", I can see something (edits or answers or bounties) that tells me what changed.

[This question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/208201/predictions-from-poisson-glmm-lme4-lower-compared-to-glm) is marked as "active today", but I don't see why.

[This meta SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371280/what-makes-a-question-active) provides the list of 'bumping' actions appended below, but none of them seem to apply here.

- **Am I missing something obvious?**
- **Are the rules for activity different on CV (and if so how)?**
- **In any case, is there a way for me to see/figure out what changed?**

(I know that's more than one question, but they're closely related ...)

---

> The following activities will cause a question to be bumped:
>
> - Addition of an answer
> - Editing the question or any of its answers (even if the answer is deleted) (with some exceptions; see Exceptions for edits bumping posts below)
> - A suggested edit gets approved [...]
> - Editing duplicates list of the question
> - Starting a new bounty (not awarding of an existing bounty, see below)
> - Successful reopening (if the question was closed previously)
> - The Community user will bump non-negatively scored, open questions every hour that have at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Community Bot" commented

> This question has answers that may be good or bad; the system has marked it active so that they can be reviewed.

Evidently this is the kind of activity referenced in the last quoted bullet of your question.

This is the third time this automated "bump" has been applied, doing so roughly at eight-month intervals.

Comment: thanks - although the question currently doesn't fulfill the criteria in the last bullet point (it does not have at least one answer scoring 0). Either (1) the existing answer scored zero at the time it was bumped and someone has upvoted it since or (2) the criteria are slightly different on CV?

Comment: I doubt the criteria are different here.  More likely they have been modified everywhere.  The record shows the answer was upvoted in 2016.